# IE9 slow loading javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

IE 9 is taking over 10 seconds to display a web page vs Chrome taking less than 3 seconds.

Is there anything we can do to speed up the loading in IE 9?

35 .js libraries are loaded, with 5 of them taking in total over 11 seconds to load on IE (vs 2 seconds on Chrome). Screenshots below show IE (top) vs Chrome (bottom) longest loading components using websitetest.com.

It's a customer-facing site, so we have no control of the user browser so can't optimise the client IE at all. We have all .css files listed first, then .js files, as per recommendations.

[image: Load times for Internet Explorer v9 for longest loading components]

[image: Load times for Chrome v45 for longest loading components]

Comment: I think its because Chrome is Caching your scripts while IE is not. Can you check that?

Comment: IE9 is the last of the very slow browsers. IE10 should perform more inline with competitors. IE9 is end of life by the way. There is no reason for anyone to still use it.

Comment: But the difference mentioned (2 over 10) is way too much.. I suspect it has nothing to do IE9 being slow..

Comment: Have you considered minifying JS/CSS files? It may not completely target performance towards IE9 based browsers but it may help reduce the load over the network.

Comment: The grey part of the loading bar is JavaScript execution right? That's taking up the majority of the time. Yes IE9 really is that slow. Easily 5 times slower than Chrome.

Comment: I agree that people should ideally be on the latest browser version, but a lot of the issues we are having are with corporately-mandated browser versions which are outside of our project scope (on the client side) and we have no power to change. These are slower to progress to the latest browser versions.

Comment: I reran the test with caches disabled on both IE9 and Chrome. The time to display on IE was 21sec, on Chrome 3sec

Answer (score 1):

A entire response to your question will be far too long. I can only give some hints :

- Don't provide 35 javascripts files. Provide only one and minify it
- Test and be sure that IE9 use its cache with your static files (javascript, css, images ...)
- IE9 is very slow with Javascript. Especially with on thing : modifying the DOM. Be sure to manipulate your DOM only when you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have much of an option to reduce the number of .js files, many are standard for the frameworks we're using: bootstrap, highcharts etc. We can test locally to check that IE9 uses its cache with our static files, but the site is customer facing so we don't have control of the client side browser that will be used.